# Javascript function delete media query effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a website that's look like this image:

[image]

The idea is when clicking on the button of the aside menu the aside menu will close and the bigwrapper will expand its size to fit the blank space so the result will look like this

[image]

I have written a function in Javascript to this and it just worked right, however, I wanted to make a media query that let the menu and the menu button disappear when the screen size get less than 840px it also worked

Now the problem is if someone clicked the button before the media query executed the media query effect will get disabled I think that javascript function delete the media query effect how can I fix that here is the code

```
 <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <img class="menuicons" src="images/icons/menu/home2.png" alt=""><a     href="#">Home</a>
        <img class="menuicons" src="images/icons/menu/offer.png" alt=""><a href="#">Offers</a>
        <img class="menuicons" src="images/icons/menu/cart4.png" alt=""><a href="#">Cart</a>
        <img class="menuicons" src="images/icons/menu/about.png" alt=""><a href="#">About us</a>
        <img class="menuicons" src="images/icons/menu/contact us.png" alt=""><a href="#">Contact us</a>
    </div>

       <div id="menu_button" onclick="nav();categoriesScaler()">
        <img src="images/icons/menu2.png" alt="Not availabale" />
    </div>


   <div id="bigwrapper">
    <!--Some content goes here-->
   </div>
```

here is the function

```
 <script>
   var hidden = false;

function nav()
 {
 if(hidden == false)
 {
     closeNav();
     hidden  = true;
 }
  else
   {
    openNav();
    hidden = false; 
  } 
 }


  function openNav()
   {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "30%";
    document.getElementById("bigwrapper").style.width = "60%";
    document.getElementById("bigwrapper").style.marginLeft = "35%";
   }

  /* Close/hide the sidenav */
  function closeNav() 
   {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("bigwrapper").style.width = "90%";
    document.getElementById("bigwrapper").style.marginLeft = "5%";
   }

 </script>
```

here is the css for  bigwrapper and sidenav at the end will be the media query

```
/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
height: 800px; /* 100% Full-height */
width: 30%; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
/*position: relative; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
/* top: 0;
left: 0;*/
background-color: #292929; /* Black*/
overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
transition: 0.4s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
float: left;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 25px;
color: #818181;
display: block;
margin-bottom: 25px;
transition: 0.3s;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
color: #f1f1f1;
 }



/*big wrapper*/
#bigwrapper
{
border : 1px solid #000;
width : 60%;
margin : 0 5% 0 35%;
min-height: 800px;
background:   #F5F5F5;
padding: 3%;
box-sizing: border-box;
transition: 0.4s;

}
```

here is the media query

```
@media screen and (max-width : 840px)
{
.sidenav,#menu_button
{
    display: none;
}

#bigwrapper
{
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
}
```

Sorry cause the question is too long.

Comment: It's not "click button before media query executes" timing. It happens because the click sets inline style which is more important styling. Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Ah I think I understand now. If browser is wider than 840px and click button sets style on #bigwrapper, and it won't go away when screen becomes less than 840px wide, and it must go back to the media query styles... is that correct?

Comment: yeah this is the problem how to fix it please

Comment: I will give you an answer soon. I'm thinking about how to do it without messing up your hidden = true/false logic.

Comment: ok thanks am waiting for your reply appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The widths set by your openNav and closeNav functions seem to be in line with the css, so we can simply use those functions based on width, testing using resize event.

I think the following should work, and the nav should reappear when the browser goes back to > 840px. Add this at the bottom of your script:

```
window.onresize=function(){
   if (window.outerWidth <= 840) {
       closeNav();
   } else {
       openNav();
   }
}
```

Also your button is not visible (outside media query), so add this to your CSS:

```
#menu_button {
    display: block; /* or similar style */
}
```

BTW, this would be a lot simpler using a class based system. Instead of setting styles you could add classes. When clicking the button you could add `.open` class to `.sidenav` (and next button click remove `.open`). Then in your media queries you could style `.sidenav.open { display:none}` You could do similar things with the width of the other elements. You can also check if `.sidenav` has this `.open` class instead of using var hidden. Much simpler.